# Should I create an interface for abstract class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Is there any practial reason to create interface for abstract class? I encountered such thing:

```
public interface IEntity<T> 
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity { 
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T> 
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

and i really don't understand what is the difference between that and this code, because IEntity is not a thing i whould use more than once:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { 
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your goal, and why have you started to solve your problem by doing this? It's impossible to say what is a good idea and what isn't without knowing what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091837/c-sharp-abstract-class-implementing-an-interface, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163641/interfaces-on-an-abstract-class, try searching.

Comment: Some guidance from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: kai, i want to desribe structure of database entities. I thought that it would be nice to make BaseEntity class with implementation of general properties and inherit other classes from it.

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev The fact that the suggested base-class would contain general properties or methods, is critical for its reason to exist, and it something you should have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, the first link is exatly what i wanted to know. All searches showed only "difference between abstract class and interface".

Answer (score 0):

Since the `BaseEntity` class does actually add any properties of methods, yes, it is completely different from the interface. The interface defines a property `Id` of type `T`, and that interface (contract) can be used in other locations in your application.

The base class as it is now, is useless IMHO.

A base class which would implement the interface for you is something that would be usable, like this:

```
public interface IEntity<T> {
    T Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<T>: IEntity<T> { 
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity<T> {
    // No need to implement the Id property, we already have it inherited
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same thing with correct answer that i wanted to know: [c# Abstract Class implementing an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091837/c-sharp-abstract-class-implementing-an-interface?lq=1)

Thanks everyone for help.